# Splitting with more than one delimiter

Tags: split, hashtable, delimiter

I have something like this

```
name, definition;
name, definition;
name, definition;
```

in a txt file

and i want the name as the key and the definition as the value that is stored in a hashtable

i know how to split with one delimiter in a array but im not sure how to do it with two into a hashtable

in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

New code that I actually tested instead of pseudocode (it still may have bug gaps, but the theory of converting a double deliminated list to a dictionary is working):

```
public static void DoubleParse()
{
    String input = "key1, value1; key2, value2; key3, value3;";
    input = input.Replace(" ","");
    String[] keyValues = input.Split(';');
    Dictionary<String,String> result = new Dictionary<String,String>();
    foreach(String keyValue in keyValues){
       String [] kv = keyValue.Split(',');
        if(kv.Length == 2) //make sure key and value found
            result[kv[0]] = kv[1];
    }
    foreach( KeyValuePair<String,String> kvp in result){
        Debug.WriteLine("Key is :" + kvp.Key + " for value : " + kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

With output:

```
Key is :key1 for value : value1
Key is :key2 for value : value2
Key is :key3 for value : value3
```

Comment: the ide im using doesnt have a "put" function >.>

i forgot to mention in using c#

Comment: i think the logic should still be the same. In c sharp you can use result[key] = value instead.

Comment: im getting a null reference for the this line

`result[kv[0]] = kv[1]; `